# Concerns Regarding CoreData Lightweight Migration Impact on CloudKit Schema Deployment

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I've performed a lightweight migration on CoreData to add a new query index. Testing locally, the migration appears to work fine. However, I'm concerned about the data schema in CloudKit.

Based on information from [Releasing new Core Data Schema to iCloud production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777137/releasing-new-core-data-schema-to-icloud-production) , I executed the following code to ensure schema initialization for CloudKit:

```
let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerSchemaInitializationOptions()
try? container.initializeCloudKitSchema(options: options)
```

Despite this, when deploying the schema change from development to production, there seems to be no changes. Is this expected behavior, or have I missed some steps?

[image]

Could it be possible that adding a new query index in CoreData does not affect the data schema in CloudKit?

Thank you.